# How kickass.to is sending remote url/file in our own browser without sending us to other site?

Tags: javascript, html, torrent

If you go to

```
http://kickass.to/slackware-14-0-x86-dvd-iso-t7285879.html
```

and click on the **Download Torrent** link which is just under the  title.

You will be presented with the .torrent file.

But if I copy the same hyperlink code and place it in newly created html file and upload it to my server then when I click the link, I get transferred to the torache url then there I get the file to download.

This works even if the html file is placed on my pc but not on server. How come ?

```
<a rel="nofollow" title="Download verified torrent file" href="http://torcache.net/torrent/93D92EAB697788D845FA9DDE204FA13E72189CA6.torrent?title=[kickass.to]slackware.14.0.x86.dvd.iso" class="siteButton giantButton    verifTorrentButton"><span><em class="buttonPic"></em>
            Download torrent</span>
    </a>
```

How are they doing it, without sending us to the torcache site?

How can I achieve something like that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/8LT8C/

---

**UPDATE**

i have managed to open an iframe in 0 pixel , it does the trick but its still not perfect way to do it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getTorrent(url){
$('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" src="' + url + '" width="0" height="0"></iframe>');
};
</script>
<a href="javascript:getTorrent('http://torcache.net/torrent/8017D2B92B084F62AC0CA19A40B4182A9107CA42.torrent?title=[kickass.to]ubuntu.12.10.server.i386');">Download Now</a>
<div id="iframeHolder" style="display:none"></div>
```

its not working on jsfiddle but working on my server.

Comment: I would imagine it is a redirect, so the page in the link receives your request, then a 301 redirect sends you to the 'real' location of the link. Much like all facebook links, google search results etc. A google search for `hello` has a first results to hello magazine, with a link of `https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hellomagazine.com%2F&ei=9LnQU6bRKKPE7AaTjoCwAQ&usg=AFQjCNE2TScP1sOG-TytWVe-kB0UUbWncg&bvm=bv.71667212,d.ZGU`

Comment: or is the torcache site is checking who the refereer is and if its kickass then throw file else show page. something like this ?

Comment: @Djave thanks for your input , is it possible to achieve it ? provided i dont have any control over page in link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are detecting the referrer URL and routing you to a different location if the referrer isn't set to their domain.

You can test this yourself using a tool like Fiddler to make raw HTTP requests.  If you make a request with this header:

```
Referer: http://kickass.to/slackware-14-0-x86-dvd-iso-t7285879.html
```

Then you get a 302 response to a torrent file.  However, if you use this header:

```
Referer: http://example.com/test
```

You get a 200 OK response with a page.  This is common practice to prevent people from hot-linking, while capturing some extra traffic along the way.

The only way around this is server-side.  You would have to proxy requests, and I'm sure that kickass.to wouldn't be too happy seeing a ton of traffic coming from a single IP, and they would block you quickly.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation, i didnt know how to check the headers ,

Answer (score -1):

guys!!!
i have the same problem with my internet provider
i think the redirection depends upon with the provider because when i change the internet using a usb modem with another provider such as Orange or Airtel there is no problem,so i'm downloading torrents files with those providers and i use my provider to download and share my big files!
i think we can not bypass that redirection!